Creating a new column as a mean of multiple other columns while excluding cases that have more than one missing value
I am trying to create a variable using the mutate function which is the mean score of multiple other variables while excluding observations that have more than one missing value. The code I am using will just factor out the missing value from it's calculation and continue to calculate the mean.
h18lb_r <- h18lb_r %>% mutate(social_network_contact_mean = rowMeans(h18lb_r[c(QLB008A, QLB008B, QLB008C, QLB008D, QLB012A, QLB012B, QLB012C,QLB012D, QLB016A, QLB016B, QLB016C, QLB016D), na.rm=TRUE]))


Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `social_network_contact_mean = rowMeans(...)`.
Caused by error in `[.data.frame`:
! unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)

I would like a new column with the mean score for the combined variables while excluding observations that have more than one missing value.

Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(<your data frame>) into your post or dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data.

I think the issue with your code is that the , na.rm = TRUE needs to be outside the ]. For a more tidyverse way of doing it see https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rowwise.html

Try: rowMeans(pick(c(QLB008A, QLB008B, QLB008C, QLB008D, QLB012A, QLB012B, QLB012C,QLB012D, QLB016A, QLB016B, QLB016C, QLB016D)), na.rm=TRUE). You can use any tidy-select helper to pick columns. For example, if they are all in sequence then you can simply do QLB008A:QLB016D.

I think you may be subsetting the rowMeans function wrong. There are multiple ways to subset but this one worked for me!
data <- data.frame(x=c(4,3,4,4,99),
                  y=c(4,NA,3,2,4),
                  z = c(88,NA,4,4,5),
                  w = c(4,5,2,3,4))

h18lb_r <- data %>% mutate(avg_mean = rowMeans(subset(data, select = c(`x`,`y`,`z`,`w`)), na.rm = T))

